# Anyone else getting an undefined object when promising firebase.auth().signOut() in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

My logout function is listed below. As well as how I'm implementing it. Not sure what's causing my promise to come back as undefined. It's not a binding issue. I've already tested that.

```
logout() {
  firebase.auth().signOut()
    .then((respnose) => {
      console.log(respnose)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error on logging out: ' + error)
    })
}

<Header
  statusBarProps={{ barStyle: 'light-content' }}
  leftComponent={{ icon: 'menu', color: '#fff' }}
  centerComponent={{ text: 'Chat Room', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
  rightComponent={<Icon name='logout' color='white' type='material-community' onPress={this.logout}/>}
/>
```

I'm using react-native-elements.

Comment: Check the docs for [signOut](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signOut) success returns void promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this because on success it has no response but on error it has an error object so in fact you signed out successfully but it case an error since response is undefined

```
const thisClass = this; //  here is how you assign this to variable

firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
 // Sign-out successful.
    console.log('Signed Out');
  thisClass.props.myProp // here is how you can access this.props
  thisClass.setState({ myNewState }) //  here is how you can set the state

}, (error) => {
console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: This worked slightly. I noticed that my `.then` and `.catch` was not responding well to the signout function. however, it always returns an undefined object. how am I supposed to capture my props or `this.props` if it's always undefined? any suggestions?

Comment: yes you can by assign this to variable I updated my answer